# Where can I store other files other than /opt for the application contest?

Tags: application-development

I know I have to install it to /opt, but where can I store other files, like pictures which are uploaded by the user or a database file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Quickly project directory. Once you run `quickly ubuntusubmit`, a package will be created with everything in the `/opt` directory.